# If $f$ is differentiable and strictly increasing on $I$, is $f'$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I see that $f$ is continuous on $I$ as well as bijective. I would guess that $f'$ is continuous but cannot prove it or think of a counterexample. This is not homework. A straightforward answer would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tempting as it is to say yes (by Darboux's Theorem, $f'$ has the intermediate value property), the answer is no. Consider the example
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x + x^2\sin(1/x)\,,& x\ne 0 \\ 0 \,, & x=0\end{cases}$$
near $x=0$.

The derivative of $f$ is everywhere positive, say, on $[-1,1]$, but $f'$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply.